# How to send mouse coordinates through a socket

Tags: java, sockets, applet

Here is what I want to do:

Use an applet on server side to draw on an applet on client side.

My idea is to just send mouse coordinates (when the mouse is pressed and dragged) and the client will draw using those coordinates.

However I am out of ideas on how to send the coordinates as the mouse is dragged.

code when mouse is pressed:

```
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) {
    lastx = x; lasty = y;                    // Remember where the click was
    return true;
```

code for when mouse is dragged:

```
public boolean mouseDrag(Event e, int x, int y) {

    g.drawLine(lastx, lasty, x, y);   // Draw from last position to here
    lastx = x; lasty = y;                    // And remember new last position
    return true;
```

How would I send these coordinates over on a live time basis?

Comment: Could you please let me know if my solution was of any help to you?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are sending the data to the client side so I will try my best to suggest you the best possible way.

I will give you pseudocode assuming you send data in Object form from Server to the Client.

Let's say on your server a mousedown event was fired

```
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) {
    lastx = x; lasty = y;                    // Remember where the click was
    client.send(new ServerClickEvent(x, y)); //Assuming you are using objects to send details to the client
    return true;
}
```

Now on the Client side when you receive this object you can set the lastX and lastY for the Server.

So let's say whenever you get an object from the Server on the client side there is `received(Object object)` method which is fired.

What you can do is,

```
public void received(Object object){
  if(object instanceof ServerClickEvent)
       setServerLastXAndLastY(object); // where setServerLastXAndLastY method will set lastX and lastY locations of the Server on the client side.
}
```

Now when there is a drag event on the Server, you can similarly do

```
public boolean mouseDrag(Event e, int x, int y) {
    client.send(new ServerMouseDragEvent(x, y));
    g.drawLine(lastx, lasty, x, y);   // Draw from last position to here
    lastx = x; lasty = y;                    // And remember new last position
    return true;

}
```

Now on the client side you can simply do

```
 public void received(Object object){
      if(object instanceof ServerMouseDragEvent)
           drawDragLine(object); // where drawDragLine method will draw the lines by taking x and y values from object and will change the lastX and lastY locations of the Server on the client side.
    }
```